# Eurasien, eurasiatisch/eurasisch, Eurasier -- aber Asien, asiatisch, Asiate?

Tags: etymology

Wie im Titel ersichtlich, ist mir eine Unstimmigkeit aufgefallen. Nun ist es so, daß Sprache natürlich nicht durchgehend logisch ist. Allerdings sticht die Ausnahme hier schon hervor:

- Eurasien, eurasiatisch/eurasisch, Eurasier
- Asien, asiatisch, Asiate

Wieso heißt es Eurasier und nicht Eurasiate? Das entsprechende Substantiv für den jeweiligen Erdteil, sowie das Adjektiv suggerieren, daß es Eurasiate heißen müßte.

Answer (score 3):

Eine wirklich zwingende Erklärung kann ich nicht anbieten, nur eine plausible Vermutung. Laut [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Eurasier&year_start=1500&year_end=2019&corpus=de-2009&smoothing=3) scheint der deutsche Begriff "Eurasier" erstmalig um 1837 aufgetaucht zu  sein. Der Begriff "Asiat" ist dagegen schon ab 1789 nachweisbar.

Aufgrund des im 19. Jahrhundert in Europa vorherrschenden eurozentrischen Weltbilds dürfte im Wort "Eurasien", das durch Zusammenziehung von *Europa* und *Asien* gebildet wurde, der "Eur"-Teil als dominant betrachtet worden sein. Dafür spricht auch, dass dieser Wortteil am Anfang steht und nicht ein Wort wie "Asiropa" geprägt wurde.

Wird der europäische Teil von "Eurasien" als dominant betrachtet, so liegt es nahe, dass auch der Europä**er** die Wortendung in Eurasi**er** bestimmt. "Eurasiat" würde den Fokus auf den asiatischen Teil legen.

Comment: Eine durchaus plausible Erklärung. Vielen Dank. (Übrigens: Erkläruing  -> Erklärung)